# What JavaScript events qualify as "user-initiated" in iOS with regards to HTML5 video/audio?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, html5-video, html5-audio

It's a well known <del>nuisance</del> feature in iOS that events like `onload` won't start downloading video due to Apple's <del>misguided</del> brilliant "[user-controlled downloads over cellular networks](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW4)" policy.

I'm currently working on a video player that does some weird edge-case loading stuff. **What are all the events that will trigger content download via `HTMLMediaElement.play()`?**

(According to [this IBM page on Safari iOS HTML5 audio limitations](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-ioshtml5/), `onmousedown`, `onmouseup`, `onclick` and `ontouchstart` all work, at least with audio. Any others?)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it triggers any event. Have you checked the media [`readyState`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkitjs/htmlmediaelement/1632439-readystate)?